# Arduino: how to move a servo based on difference of resistance in photoresistors

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to make a solar panel that tracks the sun and in order to do that I am using 4 photoresistors. I am very new to coding but I have already coded the part that determines the resistance  of the photoresistors (for now I'm only trying with 2). I need to get a servo to move in a certain direction depending on which photoresistor has a larger resistance. Because the resistance will not be constant even when light is, I also need to have a margin where as long as the difference of both resistances is within it, the servo will not move. I tried copying over one of the examples for servo movement into my code but I can't get it to work.

Here is what I have:

```
const int sensorPin = A0;
const int sensorPin1 = A1;
int sensorValue = 0;
int sensorValue1 = 0;
float Vin = 5;
float Vout = 0;
float Vout1 = 0;
float Rref = 2180;
float R = 0;
float R1 = 0;

#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;

int pos = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(9);
}
void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  Vout = (Vin * sensorValue) / 1023;
  R = Rref * (1 / ((Vin / Vout) - 1));
  Serial.print("R: ");
  Serial.println(R);
  delay(1000);

  sensorValue1 = analogRead(sensorPin1);
  Vout1 = (Vin * sensorValue1) / 1023;
  R1 = Rref * (1 / ((Vin / Vout1) -1));
  Serial.print("R1: ");
  Serial.println(R1);
  delay(1000);

  for (R1 > R; pos = 180; pos <= 0; pos += 1) {
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }
  for (R1 < R; pos = 0; pos >= 180; pos -= 1) {
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }
}
```

Comment: "I can't get it to work." Please elaborate, what are the symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is wrong, it has four arguments. I would suggest putting the `R1 < R` part around your for-loop in an if-condition. Right now, your for loop also starts at `pos = 180`, is incremented, but the condition is `pos <= 0`. Vice versa for the second loop. Your increment/decrements and conditions are wrong. This loop never executes, even if the fourth argument is removed.

For-loop: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-for-loop

Comment: Any idea on how to make a margin?

Comment: You can substract the two R values and get their difference. When that difference is above a certain threshold, you move your servos. Maybe like this `if ((R1 > R) && ((R1 - R) > THRESHOLD)) {move_servo()};` and vice versa for the other direction.